# BigQuery Java read reliability for larger queries

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am reading 20,000+ rows of data from BigQuery in Java and using `TableResult.iterateAll()` to iterate through these. I am finding that a handful of the rows are returned twice and some are not returned at all by the iterator. I get the correct total number of rows.

The input rows include two arrays of STRUCTs so I wonder if I am hitting a size constraint. How can I verify this, or if not, why is this happening?

When I order my input query, the problem goes away, leading me to suspect that BQ is repeating the query internally after it hits some limit and getting the rows back in a slightly different order, unless the query is explicitly ordered.

```java
QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query).setUseLegacySql(false).build();
JobId jobId = JobId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
Job queryJob = bigQueryService.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).setJobId(jobId).build());
TableResult queryResults = queryJob.getQueryResults();

for (FieldValueList row : queryResult.iterateAll()) {
    // Process row
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are encountering with duplicate and missing rows when reading data from BigQuery using TableResult.iterateAll() is likely related to the way pagination is handled and how the query results are ordered. As you mentioned that you get the correct total number of rows, it indicates that the issue is not with the query itself but likely with the pagination.

`TableResult.iterateAll()` internally handles pagination to retrieve all the rows from the query results. When the result set is large, BigQuery may split the results into **multiple pages**. As you iterate through these pages, it's possible for some rows to appear more than once or be skipped altogether if there are overlapping pages or if the pagination mechanism encounters any issues.

You can also modify your query to include an `ORDER BY` clause based on a unique identifier or a stable column in your dataset. This will ensure consistent ordering of the results and may help eliminate the issue of duplicates. Using explicit ordering in your query should provide a more consistent and reliable result.

Comment: In other words pagination doesn't work?

Comment: That's about what I thought was happening, but I couldn't find docs on this. Can you point me to them please?